# Css arrow with drop shadow

Tags: css

Please consider the following fiddle. I am trying to create an arrow at the bottom of the callout which has a drop shadow. This is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmcconechy/vT4rj/

However, If i want to move the dialog around by setting the root's left/top/width.

```
left: 9px;
position: absolute;
top: 36px;
```

Then the :after arrow is out of position. The way i can see to handle this is set the after: element to `position: relative;top: 100%`. However, as soon as i do that the shape arrow is broken?

Is there anyway i can handle this so the arrow position is relative to the box size and position?

Comment: The example already has `left` and `top` set. Can you add a “broken” jsFiddle too, please?

Comment: I played with the Fiddle on Safari changing top and left and it worked fine. The arrow moved w the box.

Comment: @mike it breaks when you change the width

Comment: Excellent thanks all: Here is a new fiddle with my final result: http://jsfiddle.net/tmcconechy/ckpK6/

Comment: Since you used my solution please show some love.

Comment: @Tim, note: you left the following out of the new fiddle 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vT4rj/2/).

All I did was put a relatively positioned div around the one you want, and that's the div you move around.  As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/position), as long as there's an ancestor div that's positioned, your absolute positioning works off of the ancestor's position.

Html:

```
<div class="positioner" style="position: relative; top: 200px;">
    <div class="inline-popup"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adds an unnecessary container div. See my simpler css solution below.

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this by changing the left position on the arrow to 50% instead of a fixed px.

```
left: 50%;
```

h/t http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Comment: Note: this is the solution @Tim used in his revised fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep this arrow in absolute position, so you can set it easily anywhere you want.

To shift it bottom to top, gange top position and reverse box-shadow for instance :
http://jsfiddle.net/vT4rj/1/
and then change borders :
http://jsfiddle.net/vT4rj/3/

```
.inline-popup:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    content: "";
    height: 18px;
    left: 176px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 18px;
}
```

Comment: once you understand wich has to be updated, you can set it anywhere around the box borders